# How to find consecutive values in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been given this task to try to detect some duplicate records in a table with a large volume of rows. The table comprises 2 joined tables. So to begin with I have:

```
select 
b.event_number_id, b.tenure_number_id, a.work_start_date, a.work_stop_date, a.amount
from
MTA.mta_sow_event a, mta_tenure_event_xref b
where
a.event_number_id = b.event_number_id
```

Now we have a table to work from. The duplicate records have unique event_number_id, the reamining fields will contain identical data, so something like this:

```
| event_number_id |  tenure_number_id | work_start_date | work_stop_date |amount|
|-----------------|-------------------|-----------------|----------------|------|
|  5532733        | 688203            |     01-SEP-14   |  25-SEP-14     | 5000 |
|  5532734        | 688203            |     01-SEP-14   |  25-SEP-14     | 5000 |
```

So, this is an example of a duplicate record. There are consecutive event_number_id's and all the remaining columns have identical information. We believe that our system has been creating duplicate events for some time now (this isn't supposed to happen), so I want to query the whole joined table and find anything that has rows that have exactly the same data, but different and consecutive event numbers.

So far, I managed to make a simple query that shows me any rows that have identical information, excluding the event_number_id column:

```
select 
b.tenure_number_id, a.work_start_date, a.work_stop_date, a.amount, count(*)
from
MTA.mta_sow_event a, mta_tenure_event_xref b
where
a.event_number_id = b.event_number_id
group by
b.tenure_number_id, a.work_start_date, a.work_stop_date, a.amount
having
count(*) > 1
```

which returns:

```
|  tenure_number_id | work_start_date | work_stop_date |amount|Count(*)|
|-------------------|-----------------|----------------|------|--------|
| 688203            |     01-SEP-14   |  25-SEP-14     | 5000 |   2    |
```

The problem is, sometimes there are rows that have identical data, but could be valid, so the best we can do at this point is find any of these matching rows that have consecutive event_number_id's. This is where I am hung up. Is there a way to pull out only the rows that contain these consecutive numbers?

Comment: You are showing references to two tables,not one.  Are there duplicates in both tables?

Comment: Like I said, it is a joined table. The first table contains some of the information, but it's very key that the tenure_number_id column from the second table is included. The problem is, we are getting duplicate events for each tenure. The approach we are taking is to find out if consecutive events have the same tenure number, start date, end date and amount.

Comment: That's OK -- you can join the two tables in a query that projects the required columns, wrap it in (), and effectively treat it as a table you are querying. It's called an in-line view.

Comment: I suppose there are two approaches: 1. find duplicates, then check if they have consecutive numbers, or 2. find consecutive numbers and then find out if they're duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on a join of the data sets:

```
with cte_base_data as (
  select 
     ... your query here ...)
select 
from cte_base_data t1 join
     cte_base_data t2 on (t1.tenure_number_id = t2.tenure_number_id and
                          t1.work_start_date  = t2.work_start_date  and
                          t1.work_stop_date   = t2.work_stop_date   and
                          t1.amount           = t2.amount)
where t1.event_number_id = t2.event_number_id - 1;
```

The efficiency will depend on a few factors, such as the efficiency of scanning the base tables and the size of the data sets.

It would be interesting to see a comparison of the execution plans of this method and the analytics-function methods. This common table expression-based join ought to be very efficient as it depends on hash joins, which have almost no cost as long as they stay in memory (a big question mark over that).

I'd be inclined to go for the analytic functions if the event_number_id's were not consecutive -- if there might be gaps, for instance, which would be harder to implement as a join. Given that one of them is the other incremented, I think it's worth taking a punt on a join.

Answer (score 1):

General idea: group rows with the same values (`partition by tenure_number_id, work_start_date, work_end_date, amount`), find minimal `event_number_id` for each group and row number of `event_number_id` inside group starting from zero (using analytic functions `min` and `row_number`), then compare sum of minimal ID and row number with `event_number_id`. For consecutive numbers they have to be equal:

```
with t as (select b.event_number_id, b.tenure_number_id, a.work_start_date, a.work_stop_date, a.amount
             from MTA.mta_sow_event a, mta_tenure_event_xref b
            where a.event_number_id = b.event_number_id)
select *
  from (select t.*, 
               min(event_number_id) over (partition by tenure_number_id, work_start_date, work_end_date, amount) + 
               row_number() over (partition by tenure_number_id, work_start_date, work_end_date, amount order by event_number_id) - 1 group_id
          from t)
 where event_number_id = group_id
```

Comment: You could start with  "with t as (*original query*) select * from ..."

Comment: Dmitry, very funny! Thanks for being so dedicated to work on this problem while you are falling asleep :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions [LAG and LEAD](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) for this:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc8dc/1)

```
with t as (
select event_number_id eid, b.tenure_number_id tid, 
    a.work_start_date d1, a.work_stop_date d2, a.amount amt
  from mta_sow_event a join mta_tenure_event_xref b using (event_number_id) )
select eid event_number_id, tid tenure_number_id, 
    d1 work_start_date, d2 work_stop_date, amt amount
  from (
    select t.*, 
        lag(eid) over (partition by tid, d1, d2, amt order by eid) l1, 
        lead(eid) over (partition by tid, d1, d2, amt order by eid) l2
      from t )
  where eid in (l1+1, l2-1) order by eid, tid
```